# Tomcat multiple web application different domain name on centOS

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, centos

I have a `CentOS` server and on it, I have a tomcat server. I have two clients with two web applications `eg. 131.163.121.215/application1` and `131.163.121.215/application2`

Both of those clients need a separate domain name for their web applications
eg. `www.application1.com` and `www.application2.com`
 Is that possible and if it is, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I suppose you are using the default Tomcat port (8080), You can edit the `server.xml` file on `<TOMCAT_DIR>/conf/server.xml` to add another service with a connector running on a different port for example `9090`, you then place your other app on the second service. With this configuration you can add your application on a different folder for example `webapps2`

Example of server.xml

```
...
<Service name="Service1">
<Connector port="8080" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="250"/>
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
</Service>

<Service name="Service2">
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="300" connectionTimeout="20000" />
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
</Service>
...
```

Your tomcat directory should have 2 webapps folders with your applications:

`<TOMCAT_DIR>/webapps/application1`

`<TOMCAT_DIR>/webapps2/application2`

The domains will redirect to the same server but to different port:

**www.application1.com** -> `131.163.121.215:8080/application1`

and

**www.application2.com** -> `131.163.121.215:9090/application2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand what you are trying to achieve, tested it and it works! For my current situation, i've managed to do it by adding a new host with valve inside the same service.